# Are there ways of increasing the execution speed of mysqli->prepare?

Tags: php, performance, mysqli, phpunit

My tests are running pretty slow... I've got under 100 tests, but it still takes over 10 seconds to run on a fast machine. I tried disabling code coverage, and using caching for the couple of things I do that hit remote servers (e.g. LDAP).

Profiling the tests while PHPUnit is running produces:

[image: screenshot]

fully 10% of the running time -- which includes the time to gather info for and generate a lot of pages for code coverage -- is spent in `mysqli->prepare`. Unfortunately, I can't abstract the database out here. Not only am I effectively testing a database access layer itself, a lot of logic is implemented in terms of `JOIN`s inside the code under test.

Are there any configuration settings I can change or anything of that nature to make this faster? Does `prepare` require calling out to the mysql server (and therefore setting up a  local mysql server for testing might help?)

Comment: If prepare and crypt takes up 2seconds, even if you can optimize them away what is taking up the other 8??? What are you going to do about the oher 8seconds? Are you sure you want to bother?

Comment: @acidzombie24: I'm not saying that I'm ignoring the rest. But I know where the rest comes from (and therefore have little reason to ask on SO about it). Plus, when working on perf issues, it's always better to focus on the bits that are taking the most time first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, a `prepare()` statement will call out to the MySQL server. Prepared statements are executed server-side in two calls: a `PREPARE` call, and an `EXECUTE` call.

Per example:

```
mysql> PREPARE stmt1 FROM 'SELECT * FROM mysql.user';
mysql> EXECUTE stmt1;
```

Same goes for any driver, whether it is the PHP driver of a JDBC driver. To further prove that it in fact does make a call, execute this code:

```
$mysqli->prepare('SELECT * FROM mysql.user');
```

...and you can see the following in MySQL:

```
mysql> show processlist;
+-----+------+-----------+------+---------+------+-------+--------------------------+
| Id  | User | Host      | db   | Command | Time | State | Info                     |
+-----+------+-----------+------+---------+------+-------+--------------------------+
| 564 | root | localhost | NULL | Query   |    0 | NULL  | show processlist         |
| 565 | root | localhost | NULL | Prepare |    0 | NULL  | SELECT * FROM mysql.user |
+-----+------+-----------+------+---------+------+-------+--------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

To accelerate this, you can use **UNIX domain sockets** on the local machine (assuming you have a POSIX OS). This removes the overhead of TCP handshaking and error correction, as well as network lag since it is executed locally.

The best solution, however, is in fact to abstract your database connections using mock objects, but you already knew that. A unit test is not a unit test if it must connect to a database: it's an integration test.

Comment: +! -- but "A unit test is not a unit test if it must connect to a database" <-- I would argue this is false. It is only true if you don't rely on the database to enforce data integrity for you. You can mock out the DB and look for queries, but your tests shouldn't care about the queries, only the results.

Comment: @Billy ONeal: Anything that relies on a dependency cannot be a unit test, because when it does, it is testing more than one unit of code. Two units of code would make it a *units* test. :) Besides, if your DB fails, crashes, etc. your test will fail even if the code and test are 100% valid, and a unit test should fail only if either is badly written, not if an external component is not behaving as expected.

Comment: The problem with that definition is one's definition of "component". One man's component is another person's module is another person's system. When speaking about code which serves to "front the database", the behavior of the database is the end product of the code. Attempting to test that code as a unit without running against a database is not possible because the change in the state of the database is the function of the code.

Comment: Put another way, how do you propose separating the DB and code which does nothing but execute a join from each other? If the behavior is not separable, then how can the two not be part of the same unit?

Comment: @Billy ONeal: I usually abstract the database in a way that makes it easy to unit test (i.e.: dependency injection). When done properly, the fake "database" always returns what the caller expects. So, say your database call is in `Model_User::validate()`, you provide a class `DB_MySQL` to that model class to perform the request. In unit testing mode, you provide it with a `DB_MySQL_ValidateMock` class that always return the expected value (i.e.: you hardcode it). There is no way that the test fails because your fake "database" class returns invalid data: it can only return the expected result.

Comment: But then you aren't testing anything. (The logic in the code is encapsulated in the query, and you didn't look at the query)

Comment: @BillyONeal: First, code has to be made testable. In order to do so, you must generally use the Factory Pattern. You could make these simple changes to it: [ideone.com/54Foz](http://ideone.com/54Foz). After that, it's just a matter of mocking and faking. You pass your tested method mock and fake copies of objects for the sole purposes of logging and keeping the flow going, respectively. You then return a response that the program expects. Once the call ends, you know *everything* that happened in there and can make all the assertions you want: http://ideone.com/IVZ54

Comment: And the query itself can be tested by checking the parameters passed to your dependency (the adapter). If the database can't handle it, that's a different problem that integration testing will handle.

Comment: Then either that is a single Unit (including the database), or B. unit testing that kind of code (which is most all the code in my codebase) is not worthwhile. Mocking out the dependencies makes the test too brittle, and tests implementation details rather than requirements of clients of that code. There's no reasonable way to mock things there such that it works if someone changes the query in the future, even if the changed query is correct. Again though, I would still call a test which calls on the database a unit test, because I'm thinking units of behavior rather than units of code.